# Как отправить значения текстовых полей формы в БД при помощи AJAX?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, postgresql

Здравствуйте.
В AJAX новичек, поэтому прошу помощи.

Есть сервлет:

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   //
}

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
}
```

и есть JSP-страница с полями формы для заполнения:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"
     isELIgnored="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Форма обратной связи</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript">
function autoPopulate_resultAction_receiver(targetElement) {
    if (targetElement.options[targetElement.selectedIndex].value == '-1') {
        return;
    }
    targetElement.form.elements['receiver'].value = targetElement.options[targetElement.selectedIndex].value;
}
</script>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FDF5E6">

<H1 ALIGN = "CENTER">Форма обратной связи</H1>

<form ACTION = "/servlet/ShowParameters" METHOD = "POST">

    <H3 align = "LEFT">Отправитель:</H3>

    Фамилия: <input TYPE = "TEXT" NAME = "FirstName">
    <br><br>

    Имя: <input TYPE = "TEXT" NAME = "SecondName">
    <br><br>

    Отчество: <input TYPE = "TEXT" NAME = "LastName">
    <br><br>
    <hr>
    <br>

    Получатель:<select onChange = "autoPopulate_resultAction_receiver(this);">
                    <option value = "-1">Укажите получателя</option>
                    <option value = "ivan@mail.ru">Иванов Иван Иванович</option>
                    <option value = "petr@mail.ru">Петров Петр Петрович</option>
                    <option value = "sidor@mail.ru">Сидоров Сидор Сидорович</option>
                    <option value = "alex@mail.ru">Алексеев Алексей Алексеевич</option>
               </select>

    <br><br>
    Тема: <input TYPE = "TEXT" NAME = "Theme">
    <br><br>

    Текст сообщения:
    <textarea NAME = "message" ROWS = 3 COLS = 40></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>

    <input TYPE = "SUBMIT" VALUE = "Оформить заказ">

</form>
<br>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Поля на форме вводятся, всё ок.

Но мне сейчас как то надо, при помощи AJAX-запроса, отправить эти поля в виде одной записи в бд PostgreSQL.

Товарищи, как сделать передачу в бд? Буду крайне рад подсказке! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сервлете:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    String firstName = request.getParameter("FirstName");
    String secondName = request.getParameter("SecondName");
    //и т.д. ваши параметры из формы
    //для проверки System.out.println("firstName = " + firstName);
    //тут сохраняете данные в БД
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

В html файле:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Форма обратной связи</TITLE>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function autoPopulate_resultAction_receiver(targetElement) {
            if (targetElement.options[targetElement.selectedIndex].value == '-1') {
                return;
            }
            targetElement.form.elements['receiver'].value = targetElement.options[targetElement.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/servlet/ShowParameters",
                data: $('#formId').serialize()
            }).done(function (res) {
                alert("send by ajax");
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FDF5E6">

<H1 ALIGN="CENTER">Форма обратной связи</H1>

<form ACTION="/servlet/ShowParameters" method="post" id="formId">

    <H3 align="LEFT">Отправитель:</H3>

    Фамилия: <input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="FirstName"> <br><br>

    Имя: <input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="SecondName"> <br><br>

    Отчество: <input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="LastName"> <br><br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    Получатель:
    <select onChange="autoPopulate_resultAction_receiver(this);">
        <option value="-1">Укажите получателя</option>
        <option value="ivan@mail.ru">Иванов Иван Иванович</option>
        <option value="petr@mail.ru">Петров Петр Петрович</option>
        <option value="sidor@mail.ru">Сидоров Сидор Сидорович</option>
        <option value="alex@mail.ru">Алексеев Алексей Алексеевич</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Тема: <input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Theme"> <br><br>

    Текст сообщения: <textarea NAME="message" ROWS=3 COLS=40></textarea> <br><br>
    <br><br>

    <input TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Оформить заказ POST">

    <input type="button" onclick="sendData()" value="Оформить заказ AJAX"/>

</form>
<br>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

А для сохранения в БД можете использовать к примеру JDBC.

Comment: А сохранять данные в БД как? Я к примеру знаю реквизиты подключения к PostgreSQL из файла конфигурации Hibernate:           <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://server:5432/DB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">P@ssw0rd</property>

Comment: Если в проекте уже есть подключенный Hibernate, то используйте его, посмотрите как его использовали в каком нибудь сервисе. Ну или на крайний случай сюда выложите примеры запросов из проекта.

Comment: Обьясните пожалуйста, зачем в теле doPost-метода нужен ещё в конце вызов doGet-а ?

Comment: Вызов doGet-а не обязателен, если вся логика работы с запросом закончилась, то не нужно вызывать, я скопировал с вашего кода.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо. Ещё вопросик: правильно ли я понял, что тот пример который Вы привели - это и есть AJAX запрос ?

Comment: Мне этот момент принципиальный. Задание такое. т.е. передача с помощью AJAX. Вот и хочу понять - это и есть AJAX?

Comment: добавил код с хтмл, необходимо только библиотека jQuery

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Всё классно! Но теперь (после отказа от submit) при переходе на обработчик Ajax перестала работать валидация полей. Нашел пример как делать на Ajax но там php ((  Как проверить что если поля пустые, высветить ошибку или вернуть обратно?

Comment: Сделал. Воспользовался примером отсюда: http://poleshuk.ru/proverka-zapolneniya-polej-formy-na-javascript/